# a noisy sound is came out from HDD (nokia booklet 3G)

Tags: 10.04, nokia

I just installed Ubuntu LTS 10.04 on my Nokia Booklet 3G. It's working smoothly. But I found a problem. I heard a noisy sound from HDD when I turned off the booklet. What should i do to resolve this issue? thanks before

Comment: FIRST - save your important files someplace not on the Booklet!  Then follow guntbert's advice

Comment: yes, i agree with you, but there is no immportant data actually, because the ubuntu is installed a week ago

Answer (score 0):

first of all, I would suggest you installing at least some minimal version of LTS 12.04 (if possible).

Anyway, I still would be smart performing some HDD sanity check.
For example something like this: http://www.howtoforge.com/checking-hard-disk-sanity-with-smartmontools-debian-ubuntu

Comment: He should do it the other way round: check the hardware before installing anything.

Comment: i already knew that the hdd is Toshiba MK1235GSL 120 GB Super Silent HDD. where should i find the drivers?

Comment: and changing to LTS 12.04 probably will not meet the requirements